# how should i create the mongodb databse design for below criteria

Tags: node.js, mongodb

suppose I have 6 specific details to save to user details and the same details want to fetch by admin and he can also register the same detail for a user. then what should be the mongodb database design to tackle this issue.

Comment: As far as I understood you want only an admin could save/retrieve data into/from `details` property of a MongoDB `User` Document? Clarify your question, please.

Comment: no, i mean i am user and i want to register and i have personel, address, contacts details are schemas of mongodb and i want to give full right to a admin that he can also create the full user details and give to some user. so he can login and see their details.